# "Found no citation" etc. BibTeX error when I have no bibliography

Tags: bibtex, errors, texmaker

Here is an extremely minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
Hello, World!
\end{document}
```

Using TeXMaker, quick compiling (PDFLaTeX + BibTeX + PDFLaTeX * 2) this example gives the following error when it is BibTeX's turn:

> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) The top-level auxiliary file: test.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file test.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file test.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file test.aux (There were 3 error messages)

Obviously it won't find any citation commands since I have no bibliography.

However on my previous computer, quick compiling this document would work correctly, in that BibTeX would not produce any error (as I think it should)

Why is it doing that now?

Comment: Have a look at the settings and uncheck to run bibtex when quick building.

Comment: you did not use `\cite{<bibid>}`?

Comment: @Johannes_B I imported TeXMaker's configuration from my previous computer. Moreover I don't want to have to switch between different compilation processes depending on what document I'm working on.

Comment: @Naphaneal The example I put in my question gives me this error, so no I did not use any cite command.

Comment: @FataIize I know, but as @Johannes_B pointed out, your compile process expects citations, bibliography and -style. if you customize your process to leave out the `bibtex` run, they won't show up.

Comment: My compile process on my previous computer also expected them and it didn't give me any error when there was no bibliography. As I've said I don't want to switch between compile processes depending on what document I am working on. A PDFLaTeX + BibTeX + PDFLaTeX * 2 should work regardless of whether I have bibliography or not in the document, which it did on my previous computer.

Comment: bibtex has always given that warning, so if you did not see it previously either bibtex was not being run, or the editor on the other machine was hiding the bibtex log.

Comment: Except that here I get an error, not a warning, which completely stops the compile process (since the first thing is PDFLaTeX and I have no bibliography it's fine, but I can't see the compile warnings of PDFLaTeX at the end, because it displays the error of BibTeX instead).